# Add expire headers for scripts that are not on my server?

Tags: hyperlink, header, web, external

I have a wordpress website and I added the expire headers on all pages/images and scripts but I don not know how I could add expired headers to external scripts.

For example google, bing translator and facebook.

All the above is my problem, some other scripts from external websites are the real problem, they don't have expire headers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is creating weblinks in wordpress and then linking those from the main home page to the social, or external link so it looks like it's still coming from your domain so for example using weblinks would be something of the effect like below

```
 http://www.stackoverflow.com to http://www.google.com/stackoverflow.com
```

This works pretty smooth and it cuts your SEO by a few percent.  Try it on GTM (https://gtmetrix.com). Works great for all external sources.

1. So add external source to weblinks
2. Change link from page to link to internal link forwarding to external link.
3. On all links use for example weblinks/(to external link here), not http://www.domain.com, etc.

That should do it!

Comment: Let me try it and see how it goes.

Comment: I added my domain http://mydomain {linking to} http://google.com/profile weblink and working perfectly.